# Exception 400 thrown from Validator get rewrapped into another exception with http code 500

Tags: java, annotations, tomcat7, jax-rs, bean-validation

I'm wrote an annotation for JAX-RS Query params coupled with a validator.
Code is executed when expected.

The goal is to send a chosen status code like 400 if the query param is missing. 
Jersey sends 404 by default which does not suit.

If the exception is thrown from the endpoint, its ok : the client gets a 400 error.

If the WebApplicationException is thrown from the validator, it gets rewrapped into a 500 error.

I could roll a method in the parent class of my endpoints, to be executed at the beginning of every endpoint w/ mandatory params but I'd rather have consistency by using an annotation.

**Q:** How can I have my annotation's exception be sent as is to the client ?

I already tried custom ExceptionMappers. 
Although annoted with @Provider and package added to scan list, they are not used. Even the ExceptionMapper < ConstraintViolationException>

**Environment**

Maven, Spring based project
Jersey v2.23.1
okhttp 2.0.0 and 2.7.5
Tomcat 7.0.47 and 55
jersey-bean-validation is in use

BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE :  true
BV_DISABLE_VALIDATE_ON_EXECUTABLE_OVERRIDE_CHECK : true

**Annotation**

```
@Target({java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy={MustExistValidator.class})
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@Documented
public @interface MustExist {...}
```

**Validator**

```
@Provider
@SupportedValidationTarget(ValidationTarget.PARAMETERS)
public class MustExistValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MustExist, List<Integer>> {
...
@Override
public boolean isValid(List<Integer> integerList, ConstraintValidatorContext context)
{
  if (integerList == null || integerList.isEmpty()) {
     context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
  //         throw ResourceException.emptyParameter(field);  // custom Exception : a WebApplicationException w/ status 400  : becomes 500 (KO)

     Response.ResponseBuilder builder = Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
     builder.entity("Missing 'indicators' query parameter.");
     Response response = builder.build();
     throw new WebApplicationException( ResourceException.emptyParameter(field), response);
 // This is to populate a cause. So that its not replaced. KO too (500).

  }
  return true;
```

}

Comment: My question is different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833553/jax-rs-service-throwing-a-404-httpexception-but-client-receiving-a-http-500-code?rq=1 as I want to throw the exception from the validator

Answer (score 0):

Well, my solution fits in the category "deal with it and work around".

Unfortunately, the exception deliberately thrown in the annotation's validator gets wrapped by jersey/tomcat.

So my solution, is to write a mapper for the wrapped exception. 
Get the cause and do what must be done.

```
@Component
@Provider
public class ValidationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationException> {

   @Override
   public Response toResponse(ValidationException exception) {
       if (exception.getCause() != null
            && exception.getCause() instanceof WebApplicationException) {
```